# MS SQL SERVER BACKUP Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In sql server 2008, i have taken Full backup type of my database and database was successfully done.My question is while restoring it how can i check or know that my whole backup was perfect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189587.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 0):

See [Detecting and Coping with Media Errors During Backup and Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189055.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The DB won't come on-line if something is wrong most likely.

Although, you can run [RESTORE VERIFYONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189587.aspx), you're more likely to restore the wrong DB or from the wrong backup file to be honest.

If you want you could run DBCC CHECKDB.

I tend to query a known table for the last "updateddatetime" column

Comment: thanks buddy ,RESTORE VERIFYONLY does not attempt to verify the structure of the data contained in the backup volumes. i cant get wht is - structure of the data ?

Comment: @Dhivagar: what do you mean? DBCC CHECKDB on a backup file?